# Base R way of counting by multiple groups

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to count instances based on many categorical variables using only base R.

Sample data:

```
create_sample <- function(){sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 500, replace=T)}
df <- data.frame(
          x1 = create_sample(),
          x2 = create_sample(),
          x3 = create_sample(),
          x4 = create_sample()
        )
```

Normally I'd use dplyr and do something like this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(count = 1) %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2, x3, x4) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

To get the dataframe output I want:

```
# A tibble: 55 x 5
# Groups:   x1, x2, x3 [?]
   x1    x2    x3    x4    count
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
 1 A     A     A     A      3.00
 2 A     A     B     A      1.00
 3 A     A     B     B      1.00
 4 A     A     B     C      2.00
 5 A     A     C     B      1.00
 6 A     B     A     A      3.00
 7 A     B     A     B      2.00
 8 A     B     A     C      1.00
```

But now I have the constraint of having to do the data manipulation with base R. One option I tried was something like:

```
as.data.frame(table(df$x1, df$x2, df$x3, df$x4))
```

Aside from the output being too large counting all the 0 cases, it starts to run a long time and even crash R when I have larger data

Is there a reasonable base R approach to handling multiple groups?

Comment: `aggregate(1:nrow(df) ~ x1 +x2 + x3 + x4, FUN=length, data=df)` or 
`aggregate(1:nrow(df) ~ ., FUN=length, data=df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `count` in `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
   count(!!!rlang::syms(names(.)))
```

---

In `base R`, we use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(n~ ., transform(df, n = 1), sum)
```

Or

```
aggregate(cbind(n = rep(1, nrow(df)))~ ., df, sum)
```